# How to get results of a OCaml program in OCaml? (i.e OCaml version of ProcessBuilder in JAVA)

Tags: ocaml

I'm very new to OCaml and recently studying on program verification.
For implementation, I need a library module of Ocaml that gets a result of another Ocaml program. I hope the library has the same functions as the ProcessBuilder in JAVA.

I wonder if there is such one for Ocaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, OCaml provides [facilities](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Unix.html#1_Highlevelprocessandredirectionmanagement) to create processes. Here is an example, showing how to use the `Unix.open_process_in` function,

```
# let input = Unix.open_process_in "echo 'hello, world'";;
val input : in_channel = <abstr>
# input_line input;;
- : string = "hello, world"
# input_line input;;
Exception: End_of_file.
```

You can spawn a process that runs any program, no matter in which language it is written. If you want your processes to communicate OCaml data structures, then you can use the [Marshal](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Marshal.html) module to safely translate your OCaml values to and from strings.